# Docker mkdir not creating directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

im very new to dockerfiles and want to create a directory folder via container. The image and container build successfully but folder is not created. Following is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Ibrahim

# create data folders
RUN mkdir -p -v D:\test
```

Comment: windows path syntax in linux dist? what about changing `D:\test` --> `/test` ?

Comment: This doesn't work too. From the container CLI, it shows that the folder is created but is not visible anywhere.

Comment: `FROM ubuntu mkdir D:\test` hhmmm...

Comment: Im using Docker Desktop for windows.

Comment: What base image shall I use? Windows base image?

Answer (score 1):

In linux, you have to use common slash instead of backslash. (https://phoenixnap.com/kb/create-directory-linux-mkdir-command)

`RUN mkdir -p -v /test`

Comment: Im using Docker Desktop for windows.

Comment: it doesn't mind if you are using Docker in windows...the issue is you are deploying a Linux based image.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create directory in your local machine, while you are using Docker.
You need to understand that, in basic, Docker container runs on virtual machine which basically does not even know your local machine.

From comments it seems you do want to create directory on your local machine.
You'll have to use BIND MOUNT.
It is a basically a volume which has "full" connection to your provided directory on your local machine: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Ibrahim

WORKDIR /yourWorkingDir_IN_DOCKER_CONTAINER_FILESYSTEM

# create data folders
RUN mkdir -p -v /<path_to_created_dir>
```

Then run:

```
docker run ..... -v <path_to_your_localhost_dir>:<path_to_Dir_in_docker_container>
```

Note that declaring volume in `Dockerfile` (with `VOLUME`) is not helpful for creating the volume, but only when `DOCKER RUN` with `-v` option (or with more advanced option: `docker-compose`)